# Is the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f(x)=e^{x^4}$centered at $x_0=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Am I right that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f(x)=e^{x^4}$centered at $x_0=0$ is infinity since there are no singularities?

note: x is real valued.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes!   If $ f:\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$ is entire, that is if $f'(z)$ exists and is continuous at every $z\in \Bbb C,$ then the radius of convergence of the power series for $f,$ centered at any point, is $\infty.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
e^{x^4}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^{4k}}{k!}
$$
and you require
$$
x^{4}\lim_{k\to \infty}\sup\left | \frac{1}{(k!)^{1/k}} \right|<1
$$
but that limit supremum is zero, and you may conclude that any $x$ will do.

Also note that this should be somewhat clear a priori; the factorial beats polynomial growth quite handily.

Comment: Oh I see, so indeed it is infinity since we get $x^4(0)$ basically as k goes to infinity?

Comment: yes, i.e. for the same reason that the exponential series has radius of convergence infinity

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it. :D

Answer (score 2):

Note that the radius of convergence of $$e^t = \sum _{0}^{\infty} \frac {t^n}{n!} $$is $\infty$.

Thus the series will converge at $t=x^4$ as well.

That is the radius of convergence of $$e^{x^4} =   \sum _{0}^{\infty} \frac {x^{4n}}{n!}$$ is $\infty$.

Comment: +1: I think this is a good solution because it solves the problem without computation.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for your attention.